# Sql date > date by more than 8hrs

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do a query that chart date is the system time the data was charted is more than 8 hrs after the perform date time.

I am using the following query:

```
 select * from pat_results where app_type like 'L' and (chart_dt_utc > perform_dt_utc +8)
```

The date and time format for both columns are 2012-12-29 11:44:00

Is the +8 correct?

Comment: So your two date columns are not DATETIME, but a string?  Which database are you working on, as this will probably be dependent on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  In databases that allow you to add a number to a date, the number is measured in days.

The value you want to add is 8/24.0 -- include the decimal place, because some databases calculate 8/24 as integers and give you 0.

Answer (score 1):

No, + 8 adds 8 *days*. You want:

```
select * from pat_results where app_type like 'L' and datediff(hour, chart_dt_utc, perform_dt_utc) > 8
```

Edit: Oh. For some reason I thought you were using SQL server. Well, suffice it to say, use whatever equivalent exists in your RDBMS.

Edit 2: In Oracle you can do this:

```
select * from pat_results where app_type like 'L' 
  and (chart_dt_utc > perform_dt_utc + (8 / 24))
```

Comment: it is Oracle the datediff returned ORA-00904: "DATEDIFF": invalid identifier.